# Deep copying in java via cloning

Tags: java, reference, deep-copy

I currently have two classes, Universe and World. The Universe class has a ArrayList field, that lists all of that Universe's Worlds. I want to be able to copy a Universe and then add a world to it, so that I have two Universe objects, one with one World less than the other.

This is the Universe class:

```
public class Universe {
    private ArrayList<World> worlds;
    private int worldCount;
    private boolean reflex;
    private boolean trans;
    private boolean symm;
    private boolean hereditary;

    public Universe(ArrayList<World> worlds, int worldCount, boolean reflex, boolean trans, boolean symm, boolean hereditary) {
        this.worlds = worlds;
        this.worldCount = worldCount;
        this.trans = trans;
        this.reflex = reflex;
        this.symm = symm;
        this.hereditary = hereditary;
        if (this.symm && this.trans) { // symmetry and transitivty makes reflexivity
            this.reflex = true;
        }
    }
    public Universe(Universe u) { // creates a shallow copy of the other universe
        this(u.getWorlds(), u.getWorldCount(), u.getReflex(), u.getTrans(), u.getSymm(), u.getHereditary());
    }
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        Universe u = null;
        try {
            u = (Universe) super.clone(); 
        }catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) { 
            u = new Universe(this.getWorlds(), this.getWorldCount(), this.getReflex(), this.getTrans(), this.getSymm(), this.getHereditary());
        } 
        return u;
    }
}
```

And the World class:

```
public class World {
    private Universe parentUniverse;
    private String worldName;
    private ArrayList<Relation> relations; 
    private ArrayList<ExprStr> expressions;


    public World(Universe u) {
        this.parentUniverse = u;                 
        int count = u.getWorldCount();
        String countStr = Integer.toString(count);
        this.worldName = "";
        this.worldName += 'w' + countStr;
        this.relations = new ArrayList<Relation>();
        if (this.parentUniverse.getReflex()) {
            this.addRelation(this, true, true); 
        }
        this.expressions = new ArrayList<ExprStr>();
    }
}
```

The World class names itself within its own universe, and the toString method returns that name. The toString method of Universe returns the list of all Worlds.

I have the code:

```
Universe y = new Universe();
World d = new World(y);
y.addWorld(d);

Universe x = (Universe) y.clone(); // have to type cast to use clone()
World d1 = new World(x);
x.addWorld(d1);

System.out.println(y);
System.out.println(x);
```

But the output is:

```
[w0, w1]
[w0, w1]
```

Even though, if deep copied properly, I expected that one Universe would have more worlds than the other.

Do I need to deep copy the World class too? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks heaps! :)

Comment: Yes, you need to deep copy anything you want to be a distinct reference.

Comment: You need to deep copy the `ArrayList` itself, e.g. using `new ArrayList<>(u.getWorlds())` in the copy-constructor.

Comment: Why do you even try `super.clone()` when you haven't implemented `Cloneable`? It'll fail, so why not just do the copy-constructor directly?

Comment: Youre right, I forgot to implement cloneable. Also, I didnt realise it was possible to copy an ArrayList like that, and it works without cloning, so thanks for the much simpler solution! :)